# Tensorflow code breaking

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am modifying cifar multi GPU tensorflow code to read the Imagenet dataset.

The edits that I made are:

**Cifar10.py:**

1) Changed tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir',...)

2) Removed the later part in data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')

3) Removed the download part from maybe_download_and_extract()

**cifar10_input.py:**

1) IMAGE SIZE = 227

2) result.height = 256 and result.width = 256

3) Changed

```
filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i) for i in xrange(1, 6)]
```

to

```
filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, i) for i in os.listdir(data_dir)]
```

But this is throwing an ugly error:
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_tower_0/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128, current size 0)

[[Node: tower_0/shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](tower_0/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, tower_0/shuffle_batch/n/_775)]]

[[Node: tower_1/shuffle_batch/n/_664 = _HostSendT=DT_INT32, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_170_tower_1/shuffle_batch/n", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1"]]
Caused by op u'tower_0/shuffle_batch', defined at:

File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi-gpu_train.py", line 224, in

```
tf.app.run()
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run

```
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi-gpu_train.py", line 222, in main

```
train()
```

File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi-gpu_train.py", line 150, in train

```
loss = tower_loss(scope)
```

File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi-gpu_train.py", line 65, in tower_loss

```
images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py", line 119, in distorted_inputs

```
batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py", line 153, in distorted_inputs

```
min_queue_examples, batch_size)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py", line 104, in _generate_image_and_label_batch

```
min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 496, in shuffle_batch
    return queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 287, in dequeue_many

```
self._queue_ref, n, self._dtypes, name=name)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 319, in _queue_dequeue_many

```
timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 664, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1834, in create_op

```
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
```

File "/home/saoni.m/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1043, in **init**

```
self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

When I traced back to the line where shuffle_batch() is called:

```
images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [image, label],
      batch_size=batch_size,
      num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
      capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
      min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
```

The values that are passed to it are:
batch size 128, num_threads 16, capacity 20384, min_after_deque 20000

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not getting any data input from your readers.

You changed:

```
[os.path.join(data_dir, i) for i in os.listdir(data_dir)]
```

What's actually in data_dir/ ?  (Are you sure the right dirname is being used, etc.?)

My suggestion would be to `print filenames` at the start of your execution -- that's not doing anything in tensorflow, just python, so you'll get an instant easy-to-read answer.  If it looks valid, we'll work from there. :)

The second concern is that your changes aren't enough to start working on imagenet.  The `read_cifar10` function is specialized for the cifar input format, but the ImageNet data is (mostly) JPEGs, with a separate file specifying the labels.  You can decode the jpegs with `tf.image.decode_jpeg`, but you also need to merge the synset labels in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Regarding the first concern, I have printed `len(filenames)` and it has 1300 files (one of the folders of the imagenet is what I am testing on. 

I am on the second one, but it seems complicated. Can you please elaborate that a bit more?

Comment: So you've taken the contents of, e.g., nXXXXXXX and that's data_dir?  The contents are all nXXXXXXX-YYYY-.JPG, right?

Comment: Right, so that's what comment 2 is about:  The pipeline in the cifar10 example expects the input files to be in the cifar10 binary format.  As per the [TensorFlow Cifar10 docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#model-inputs) the cifar files are fixed-length binary record files that have both the metadata and the image data in each fixed-length record..  The presentation of the ImageNet data is completely different - individual JPEG files and separate metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I meet a similar problem, and i try to change python list,like
        [os.path.join(data_dir, i) for i in os.listdir(data_dir)]
to
        files=tf.train.match_filenames_once("/path/to/data.tfrecords-*"),
        filequeue = tf.train.input_string_input_producer(files).
it works for me and you can try it.